# Precedence of &&, || and &, |

Tags: java, language-lawyer, bitwise-operators

How does precedence of `&` and `|` operators bound to precedence of `&&` and `||`? I'm reading 15.22

> The bitwise operators and logical operators include the AND operator
>   &, exclusive OR operator ^, and inclusive OR operator |.
>
> [...]
>
> These operators have different precedence, with & having the highest
>   precedence and | the lowest precedence.

But there is said anything about precendence of `&&` and `||` in corresponding clauses. For incstance, let I've the condition:

```
boolean a = true;
boolean b = false
boolean c = true;
if ( a && b | c || b){
    //to do something
}
```

Could you explain the precende by the example? **I would like to look at a reference from the Standard.**

Comment: This isn't clear.  There [are ~1 billion webpages](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java%20operator%20precedence) that have Java operator precedence tables on them; what's the issue?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The question is in formal explanation, using the JLS only.

Comment: So you don't want "an example"?  Anyway, the precedence is implied by the grammar definitions given by the JLS.  ("ExclusiveOrExpression:
ExclusiveOrExpression ^ AndExpression" and so on...)

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but don't write code based on precedence rules. Write readable code that parenthesizes operations showing your intent.   
To be honest I don't remember all rules by heart for any language and I find code that does not use parenthesis frustating (if not horrile).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I can to use google. Since, I can read about precendce, for instance, in Wikipedia. But I'm interested in formal explanation, as I've already said.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Ok, but I just explained where to find the formal answer in my previous comment.

Comment: +1, for the question, because it is surprisingly hard to derive this information solely from the JLS (even though this has no practical relevance for most programmers, except for those who are writing compilers...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section [15.2 Forms of Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2)  of the JLS says:

> Precedence among operators is managed by a hierarchy of grammar productions.

This implies that the actual definition of the precedence is somewhat hidden. The [Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) page from the Java Tutorial lists them nicely, but this is not what you asked for. In section [18. Syntax, in the **JLS 7**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html), there also was a nice list. But for Java 8, this list is no longer given explicitly.

Instead, the precedence can only be derived from the grammar itself, which of course is still specified, now in the section [19. Syntax, in the **JLS 8**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html).

For the example that you posted:

```
if (a && b | c || b) { ... }
```

The first matching rule will be

```
IfThenStatement:
    if ( Expression ) Statement
```

Then, the inner of the brackets will match `Expression`, `AssignmentExpression`, `ConditionalExpression` and `ConditionalOrExpression`, according to the rules

```
Expression:
    LambdaExpression
    AssignmentExpression

AssignmentExpression:
    ConditionalExpression
    Assignment

ConditionalExpression:
    ConditionalOrExpression
    ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : ConditionalExpression

ConditionalOrExpression:
    ConditionalAndExpression
    ConditionalOrExpression || ConditionalAndExpression
```

At this point, you'll have the "parse tree"

```
            ||
           /  \
a && b | c      b
```

The right branch, `b`, will be matched by the whole chain through the definitions of

```
ConditionalAndExpression
InclusiveOrExpression
ExclusiveOrExpression
AndExpression
EqualityExpression
RelationalExpression
ShiftExpression
AdditiveExpression
MultiplicativeExpression
UnaryExpression
UnaryExpressionNotPlusMinus
PostfixExpression
ExpressionName 
Identifier
```

(with the `Identifier` being `b`).

The left branch, `a && b | c`, will be matched

```
ConditionalOrExpression:
    ConditionalAndExpression
    ConditionalOrExpression || ConditionalAndExpression

ConditionalAndExpression:
    InclusiveOrExpression
    ConditionalAndExpression && InclusiveOrExpression
```

At this point the parse tree is

```
            ||
           /  \
          /    \
         /      \
        &&       b
       /  \
      /    \
     a    b | c
```

The `a` will be identified as an `Identifier`, the same way as it was done for `b`. The remaining part, `b | c`, will directly match

```
InclusiveOrExpression:
    ExclusiveOrExpression
    InclusiveOrExpression | ExclusiveOrExpression
```

and the identifiers `b` and `c` will be matched as before.

The final parse tree will be

```
            ||
           /  \
          /    \
         /      \
        &&       b
       /  \
      /    \
     a      |
           / \
          /   \
         b     c
```

(if I made no mistake here. That's fairly complicated...)

Comment: Yeah, that is exact what I looked for. Formal exaplnation, using JLS only. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is the order of precedence (from high to low) :

```
bitwise AND             &
bitwise exclusive OR    ^
bitwise inclusive OR    |
logical AND            &&
logical OR             ||
```

([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html))

Therefore `if ( a && b | c || b)` is equivalnt to :

`if ( (a && (b | c)) || b)`

Comment: Your source is not JLS.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv It's from Oracle. That should be good enough.

Comment: Does your source relate to Java lang spec?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Have you posted a single SO question about a practical problem, rather than language-lawyering over specs?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth If the particular problem occcurs, which I cannot solve or find instant solution with google, I'll post it on SO. You've already asked me about my posts on SO. I'll answer you one more time. I'm reading specs because I want. That is all. Anything else?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Feel free to read the specs!  But SO is meant for actual, practical problems.  Not hundreds of questions about minutiae in the language standards.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Well, to be fair, I like the minutiae from time to time .. (but not here, where it adds little/no value)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth While this certainly is the *primary* goal of SO, you have to admit that in many (if not most) cases recently, the "nitpicking" questions had the highest votes and views. ("Recently" for me means: Since I'm here...). And they can be interesting.

Comment: @Marco13: They can be, yes, in moderation.  But that's not a reason for posting [hundreds of them, and essentially nothing else](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2953119/dmitry-fucintv?tab=questions).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Well, I think this kind of questions can be good (+1) or bad (-1), regardless of their relevance for others. If someone is particularly interested in compiler construction or the more "formal", theoretical side of programming, these questions **are** relevant (for him, and possibly for his peers). However, I definitiely agree that **if**, at a certain point, one has to assume that the questions are asked "just for having been asked", they may turn into a waste of time (but I can't judge objectively whether this is the case here)

Answer (score 4):

The precedence ordering isn't stated as such in the spec but it emerges from the BNF grammar rules

```
ConditionalAndExpression:
  InclusiveOrExpression
  ConditionalAndExpression && InclusiveOrExpression

ConditionalOrExpression:
  ConditionalAndExpression
  ConditionalOrExpression || ConditionalAndExpression
```

These rules say that `x && y || z` will parse as `(x && y) || z` (a ConditionalOrExpression containing a ConditionalAndExpression as its left hand operand) rather than `x && (y || z)` (which would require the and expression to allow an or expression as an operand, which it won't without parentheses).

Thus `&&` binds more tightly than `||`.

You can construct the rest of the precedence table in the same way, by tracing through the definition of `InclusiveOrExpression` and so on.

Comment: Quite precise answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

18.1 Syntax

```
InfixOp:
        ||
        &&
        |
        ^
        &
        ==
        !=
        <
        >
        <=
        >=
        <<
        >>
        >>>
        +
        -
        *
        /
        %
```

The operators are listed in lowest-to-highest precedence here (`&` is higher than `|`, like the example you found in 15.22)